# Select a maximum value across rows and columns with grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr, max

The data below have an `IndID` field as well as three columns containing numbers, including NA in some instances, with a varying number of rows for each `IndID`.

```
library(dplyr)
n = 10
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(IndID = sample(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), n, replace = T),
                  Num1 = c(2,4,2,4,4,1,3,4,3,2),
                  Num2 = sample(c(1,2,5,8,7,8,NA), n, replace = T),
                  Num3 = sample(c(NA, NA,NA,8,7,9,NA), n, replace = T)) %>%
  arrange(IndID)

 head(dat)
  IndID Num1 Num2 Num3
1   AAA    1   NA    7
2   BBB    2   NA   NA
3   BBB    2    7    7
4   BBB    2   NA   NA
5   CCC    3    2    8
6   CCC    3    5   NA
```

For each `IndID`, I would like to make a new column `Max` that contains the maximum value for `Num1`:`Num3`. In most instances this involves finding the max value across multiple rows and columns. Within `dplyr` I am missing the final step (below) and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
dat %>%
  group_by(IndID) %>%
  mutate(Max = "???")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `pmax` to get the rowwise maxs

```
dat %>%        
   mutate(Max = pmax(Num1, Num2, Num3, na.rm = TRUE))
```

If there are many columns, we can get the column names, convert it to symbol and then evaluate (`!!!`)

```
dat %>%        
    mutate(Max = pmax(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1]), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   IndID [4]
#   IndID  Num1  Num2  Num3   Max
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 AAA       1    NA     7     7
# 2 BBB       2    NA    NA     2
# 3 BBB       2     7     7     7
# 4 BBB       2    NA    NA     2
# 5 CCC       3     2     8     8
# 6 CCC       3     5    NA     5
# 7 DDD       4     8     7     8
# 8 DDD       4     7    NA     7
# 9 DDD       4     1     7     7
#10 DDD       4     1     7     7
```

---

If this is to get the max of all 'Num' column grouped by 'IndID', there are multiple ways.

**1)**  From the above step, we can extend it to group by 'IndID' and then take the `max` of row maxs ('Max')

```
dat %>%        
    mutate(Max = pmax(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    group_by(IndID) %>% 
    mutate(Max = max(Max))
```

**2)**  Another option is to convert the 'wide' format to 'long' with `gather`, then grouped by 'IndID', get the `max` of 'val' column and `right_join` with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(dat, key, val, -IndID) %>% 
    group_by(IndID) %>% 
    summarise(Max = max(val,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    right_join(dat)
```

---

**3)** Or another option without reshaping into 'long' format would be to `nest` the dataset after grouping by 'IndID', `unlist` and get the `max` of the 'Num' columns

```
dat %>%
   group_by(IndID) %>%
   nest %>%
   mutate(data =  map(data,  ~ .x %>% 
                                mutate(Max = max(unlist(.), na.rm = TRUE)))) %>% 
   unnest
```